# What is the Android Firefox user agent string?

Tags: android, firefox, mobile, user-agent

What is the Android Firefox user agent string?

Like:

iPhone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
```

iPad:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:86.0) Gecko/86.0 Firefox/86.0
```

The *platform* part of the UA string indicates if Firefox is running on a phone-sized or tablet device. When Firefox runs on a device that has the phone form factor, there is a **Mobile;** token in the *platform* part of the UA string.

When Firefox runs on a tablet device, there is a **Tablet;** token in the platform part of the UA string instead. For example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Tablet; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0
```

> The version numbers are not relevant. Avoid inferring materials based
> on these.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox#Mobile_and_Tablet_indicators